# find 2 neighbours of given object by Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object list, e.g,

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "John", Age = 24 }, 
    new Person { Name = "Tom", Age = 35 },
    new Person { Name = "Mike", Age = 42 },
    new Person { Name = "Steve", Age = 51 }
}
```

and a person, say `{Phil, 45}`.

I'd like to find our 2 persons in the list which make given person's age are just between them. In our example, they are Mike and Steve.

Can I do this with the built-in Linq extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very efficient but you can do

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(p => p.Age);
var neighbors  = new List<Person> 
                  {orderedList .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Age > phil.Age),
                          orderedList.LastOrDefault(p => p.Age < phil.Age)};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's trivially easy to do this if you're willing to do it in two iterations:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy(p => p.Age);    // Only if not already sorted
var searchPerson = new Person { Name = "Phil", Age = 45 };
var prevPerson = sortedList.LastOrDefault(p => p.Age < searchPerson.Age);
var nextPerson = sortedList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Age > searchPerson.Age);
```

However, I have to tell you that this really simply isn't a job for the Linq extensions.  Forget about Linq.

If you actually have a `List<T>` as specified in the question, then you have the [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) method at your disposal.  If you're dealing with a pure (non-indexable) `IEnumerable<T>` instance, then just iterate it:

```
Person searchPerson = ...
Person previousPerson = null;
Person nextPerson = null;
foreach (var p in list.OrderBy(p => p.Age))
{
    if (p.Age < searchPerson.Age)
        previousPerson = p;
    else
    {
        nextPerson = p;
        break;
    }
}
```

That will get your results in one iteration and only scan the sequence as far as the first `Person` with a higher age, not to the very end.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
Person p = new Person("Phil", 45);
List<Person> sList = (from Person x in list orderby x.Age - p.Age select x).ToList();
for(int i = 0; i < sList.Count - 1; i++) {
    if(sList[i] < 0 && sList[i + 1] > 0) {
        // Found the two people - the person's age is between sList[i] and sList[i + 1]
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>
                                {
                                    new Person {Name = "John", Age = 24},
                                    new Person {Name = "Tom", Age = 35},
                                    new Person {Name = "Mike", Age = 42},
                                    new Person {Name = "Steve", Age = 51}
                                };



        //{Phil, 45}


        persons.Between(age: 45);


    }
}

public static class AgeExtensionMethod
{
    public static Person[] Between(this List<Person> person,int age)
    {
        var orderdList = person.OrderBy(p => p.Age);
        var k = orderdList.Where(p => p.Age < age).Last();
        var s = orderdList.Where(p => p.Age > age).First();

        return new[] {k, s};
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

messy, but all linq:

```
class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Age);
    }
}
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person { Name = "John", Age = 24 }, 
            new Person { Name = "Tom", Age = 35 },
            new Person { Name = "Mike", Age = 42 },
            new Person { Name = "Steve", Age = 51 }
        };

        var phil = new Person { Name = "Phil", Age = 45 };

        var findTwo = list.OrderBy(p => p.Age).Reverse().SkipWhile(p => p.Age > phil.Age).Take(1).Concat(list.OrderBy(p => p.Age).SkipWhile(p => p.Age < phil.Age).Take(1));
        foreach(var person in findTwo) {
            Console.WriteLine(person);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

OR

```
List<Person> list = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Name = "John", Age = 24 }, 
    new Person { Name = "Tom", Age = 35 },
    new Person { Name = "Mike", Age = 42 },
    new Person { Name = "Steve", Age = 51 }
};

var phil = new Person { Name = "Phil", Age = 45 };

var twoNearest = from p2 in
                (from p1 in list
                where p1.Age > phil.Age || p1.Age < phil.Age
                select new {
                    Name = p1.Name,
                    Age = p1.Age,
                    Younger = p1.Age < phil.Age
                })
            group p2 by p2.Younger into split
            from p in split
            where (p.Age == split.Max(a => a.Age) && p.Younger) || (p.Age == split.Min(a => a.Age) && !p.Younger)
            select new Person {
                Name = p.Name,
                Age = p.Age,
            };
```